# NBMA neighbor-ship process

Tags: ospf, network-core

Could someone explain what is NBMA neighbor-ship process in OSPF?
I have gone through several books but did't get satisfactory explanation.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

NBMA networks require a special OSPF network type on the connected routers' interface. This setting affects quite a few things, including the need for a Designated Router, and the timers like hello timers and dead timers.

I would recommend researching OSPF network types, as the question as you've stated is way too broad to be answered on this site. You should read the [OSPF RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2328.txt), or even vendor-specific books. On this topic, Cisco Press has a few resources, namely Routing TCP/IP Volume 1.